# Derivative of $\varphi({\bf X}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i({\bf X}) \log \lambda_i({\bf X})$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

Let $\mathbb{S}_+^n$ denote the set of $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrices. Let scalar field $\varphi : \mathbb{S}_+^n \to \Bbb R$ be defined by

$$\varphi({\bf X}) := \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i({\bf X}) \log \lambda_i({\bf X})$$

where $\lambda_1({\bf X}), \ldots, \lambda_n({\bf X})$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix ${\bf X} \in \mathbb{S}_+^n$. What is the gradient of $\varphi$?

Comment: $\mathbb{S}_+^n$ is often used to denote positive semidefinite matrices, whereas $\mathbb{S}_{++}^n$ is used for positive definite ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\def\P{P^{-1}} \def\PT{P^{-T}}
\def\p{\partial} \def\l{\lambda} \def\v{\varphi}
$The [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi//matrixcookbook.pdf) contains a particularly simple rule
for the gradient of the trace of a scalar function applied
to a matrix argument
$$\eqalign{
\v &= \operatorname{Tr}(f(X)) \quad\implies\quad
\frac{\p\v}{\p X} &= \Big[f'(X)\Big]^T
}$$
Consider the following function (and its derivative)
$$f(z)=z\,\log(z),\qquad f'(z) = 1+\log(z)$$
If the eigenvalues of $X$ are $\l_k,$
then the eigenvalues of the matrix $f(X)$ are $f(\l_k)$

Expanding the trace of the proposed function yields
$$\eqalign{
\operatorname{Tr}(f(X))
  = \sum_k f(\l_k)
  = \sum_k \l_k\log(\l_k)  \\
}$$
which is indeed the objective function.

Therefore the required gradient is
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\p\v}{\p X} &= \Big[I+\log(X)\Big]^T \\
}$$

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=1}^n}
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial} \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Assuming that all eigenvalues are distinct, and the left and right eigenvectors are
$$\eqalign{
Xu_k &= \l_k u_k,\quad X^Tw_k &= \l_k w_k \qiq
w_k^TX &= \l_k w_k^T \\
}$$
Then the derivatives of the eigenvalues wrt $X$ can be calculated as
$$\eqalign{
&Xu_k = \l_k u_k \\
&dX\:u_k + X\:du_k =  d\l_k\:u_k + \l_k\:du_k \\
&w_k^T\BR{dX\:u_k + X\:du_k} =  w_k^T\BR{d\l_k\:u_k + \l_k\:du_k} \\
&{w_k^TdX\:u_k + \c{\l_k\:w_k^Tdu_k}}
  = {d\l_k\:w_k^Tu_k + \c{\l_k\:w_k^Tdu_k}} \\
&w_k^TdX\:u_k = d\l_k\LR{w_k^Tu_k} \qiq
\grad{\l_k}{X} = \fracLR{w_ku_k^T}{w_k^Tu_k} \\
}$$
Differentiate the given function wrt $\l_k$
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\psi}{\l_k} &= {\o+\log(\l_k)}  \\
}$$
and then wrt $X$
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\psi}{X} &= \Sk\BR{\o+\log(\l_k)}\gradLR{\l_k}{X} \\
 &= \Sk\BR{\o+\log(\l_k)}\fracLR{w_ku_k^T}{w_k^Tu_k}  \\
}$$

Comment: How do you get from $w^T_kdXu_k = d\lambda_k(w^T_ku_k)$ to $\frac{\partial \lambda_k}{\partial X}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = x\log x$. Then applying the functional calculus to the definition of $\varphi$ leads to

$$ \varphi(\mathbf{X}) = \operatorname{Tr}(f(\mathbf{X})) $$

for each $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{S}^n_+$. Then the derivative of $\varphi$ is a linear functional $\ell$ on the space $\mathbb{S}^n$ of all $n\times n$ symmetric real matrices such that

$$ \varphi(\mathbf{X}+\mathbf{H}) = \varphi(\mathbf{X}) + \ell(\mathbf{H}) + o(\mathbf{H}) \qquad\text{as}\quad \mathbf{H} \to 0.$$

Our goal is to identify the linear functional $\ell$ if possible. In doing so, we may endow $\mathbf{S}^n$ with the inner product $\langle \mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y} \rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{X}^{\top}\mathbf{Y})$ and utilize the Riesz representation theorem to identify $\ell$ with an element $\mathbf{L} \in \mathbb{S}^n$ via the relation

$$ \ell(\mathbf{H}) = \operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{L}^{\top}\mathbf{H}) .$$

We claim the following:

> **Claim.** $\mathbf{L} = f'(\mathbf{X})^{\top} = f'(\mathbf{X})$.

To this end, let $\mathbf{X}_t$ be a smooth path in $\mathbb{S}^n_+$. Then $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{X}_t$ are related by

$$ \operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{L}^{\top}\mathbf{X}_0') = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\biggr|_{t=0} \varphi(\mathbf{X}_t). $$

To facilitate the computation of the right-hand side, we represent $\mathbf{X}_t$ in the form

$$ \mathbf{X}_t = \mathbf{U}_t^{\top} \mathbf{D}_t \mathbf{U}_t, $$

where $t \mapsto \mathbf{U}_t$ is a smooth path of orthogonal matrices and $t \mapsto \mathbf{D}_t$ is a smooth path of positive diagonal matrices. Then

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\biggr|_{t=0} \varphi(\mathbf{X}_t)
= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\biggr|_{t=0} \operatorname{Tr}(f(\mathbf{D}_t))
= \operatorname{Tr}(f'(\mathbf{D}_0)\mathbf{D}_0')
= \operatorname{Tr}(f'(\mathbf{X}_0)\mathbf{U}_0^{\top}\mathbf{D}_0'\mathbf{U}_0).
\end{align*}

On the other hand,

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{X}'_0
&= \mathbf{U}_0^{\top}\mathbf{D}_0'\mathbf{U}_0 + (\mathbf{U}_0^{\top})'\mathbf{D}_0\mathbf{U}_0 + \mathbf{U}_0^{\top}\mathbf{D}_0\mathbf{U}_0' \\
&= \mathbf{U}_0^{\top}\mathbf{D}_0'\mathbf{U}_0 - \mathbf{U}_0^{\top}\mathbf{U}_0'\mathbf{X}_0 + \mathbf{X}_0\mathbf{U}_0^{\top}\mathbf{U}_0'.
\end{align*}

Plugging this back, it follows that

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\biggr|_{t=0} \varphi(\mathbf{X}_t)
&= \operatorname{Tr}(f'(\mathbf{X}_0)(\mathbf{X}'_0 + \mathbf{U}_0^{\top}\mathbf{U}_0'\mathbf{X}_0 - \mathbf{X}_0\mathbf{U}_0^{\top}\mathbf{U}_0')) \\
&= \operatorname{Tr}(f'(\mathbf{X}_0)\mathbf{X}'_0) + \operatorname{Tr}(f'(\mathbf{X}_0)\mathbf{U}_0^{\top}\mathbf{U}_0'\mathbf{X}_0) - \operatorname{Tr}(f'(\mathbf{X}_0)\mathbf{X}_0\mathbf{U}_0^{\top}\mathbf{U}_0').
\end{align*}

In the last line, it turns out that the last two terms cancel out each other, since

$$ \operatorname{Tr}(f'(\mathbf{X}_0)\mathbf{U}_0^{\top}\mathbf{U}_0'\mathbf{X}_0)
= \operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{X}_0f'(\mathbf{X}_0)\mathbf{U}_0^{\top}\mathbf{U}_0')
= \operatorname{Tr}(f'(\mathbf{X}_0)\mathbf{X}_0\mathbf{U}_0^{\top}\mathbf{U}_0'). $$

Therefore it follows that

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\biggr|_{t=0} \varphi(\mathbf{X}_t)
&= \operatorname{Tr}(f'(\mathbf{X}_0)\mathbf{X}'_0)
\end{align*}

and we are done.